# Preparing Data-frame for Bokeh Consumption

Tags: python, bokeh

Trying to plot with Bokeh using a data-frame but plot is displaying empty. Beginner here; missing something fundamental.

My plot works if I hard code some basic X and Y variables so I know the issue has to do with the data-frame I'm trying to use as a source.

```
...

df = pd.DataFrame(j)

df.columns = ['Team','Type','Date','SLA_MET']

df['SLA_MET']= df['SLA_MET'].round(2)

pd.set_option('display.max_columns', 10)
print(df)
```

[image]

```
source = ColumnDataSource(df)



p = figure(background_fill_color='gray',
     background_fill_alpha=0.5,
     border_fill_color='blue',
     border_fill_alpha=0.25,
     plot_height=600,
     plot_width=1000,
     x_axis_label='Month',
     x_axis_location='below',
     y_axis_label='% SLA Met',
     y_axis_location='left',
     title='Percentage of SLA Met',
     title_location='above',
     toolbar_location='below',
     tools='save')

p.line(source=source,x='Date',y='SLA_MET')

show(p)
```

[image]

Decided to pass clean lists to plot

```
for index, row in df.iterrows(): 
    if row[2] =='Service Request': 
        sr_list.append(row[3]) 
    else: 
        inc_list.append(row[3]) 
        date_list.append(row[1])  # Only need 1 list of dates
```

Problem is dates in scientific notation and dates are not in order.
[image]

Comment: Decided to pass clean lists to plot for index, row in df.iterrows():

    #print(row[2])
    if row[1] =='Service Request':
        sr_list.append(row[3])
    else:
        inc_list.append(row[3])
        date_list.append(row[2])   problem is dates in scientific notation and dates are not in order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bokeh does not know what to do with the strings in your `Date` column. You have two options:

- convert this column to real python/numpy/pandas (numeric) datetime values, and also set `x_axis_type="datetime"` in your `figure` call, or
- use the string values as [categorical factors](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/categorical.html)

It's not clear what your intention is, so I can't recommend one vs the other.

Comment: I'm trying to plot  Date on the X axis and % SLA Met on the Y axis

Comment: That doesn't really help me make sense of plotting a line with duplicate *Month-Day* values as your data has.

Comment: thank you, I have some fine-tuning but adding the following line did the trick df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])

Comment: I can actually drop 1 set of the Month-Year, I'm still having trouble actually. Going in this direction to pass clean lists. (see above) problem is dates in scientific notation and dates are not in order.

Comment: You need to set `x_axis_type="datetime"` as I mentioned above, that will format the raw timestamps as date ticks.